# IPad Clear all fields back to start

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, reset

Im creating an internal ipad app for which will allow our employees to fill in details on a site visit they have just performed.

One of the pages in the app is a massive form where the user enters all the information. I have a reset button on this form. This button will just clear all textfields, textviews, uncheck checkboxes etc etc.

Is there a clean way to reset a view to the state as if it is brand new (not-dirty). I dont really want to go through every control on the view and set it back to nothing.

Is there a way to wipe the entire view and restart again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy-way to do this is by,

```
-(IBAction) reset
{
      YourView *obj=[[YourView alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:NO];
      [obj release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to discard your view (or the sections of it you want to reset) and recreate them. That might be as simple as:

```
//assuming you have a nib file containing some custom FormView class with your current view controller as its owner and the FormView instance in the nib bound to a 'formView' property on the controller
[self.formView removeFromSuperView];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormView" owner:self options:nil];
[self.view addSubView:self.formView];
//keep a reference to the old formView first and animate the transition as you like
```

More complex but possibly worthwhile could be to have your view objects use KVO to watch for changes to some model object exposed as a property through a delegate or on a superview. That's handy if you want the view to be able to automatically update itself in response to changes to the model coming from other parts of the view or some external source like network updates. A "reset" could then be as simple as replacing that value of the property the views are observing with a new instance of your model.